# How do I display alternative text when there are no active entries in a channel?

Tags: conditionals, advanced-conditionals

I have an events channel that displays brief information about upcoming events. Those entries are set to 'expire' when they pass a certain date. When there aren't any pending events I would like to display alternative text like “There are no upcoming events at this time. Sign up for a our Newsletter to keep up to date.”

I tried the following but it does not work because there isn't a case where there aren't any entries at all:

```
{if total_entries != 0}
<h2>{title}</h2>
<p>{event_dates}<br />
    {event_location}</p>
    {event_summary}
{if:else}
<p>There are no upcoming events at this time. Sign up for a our <a href="/contact/newsletter">Newsletter</a> to keep up to date.    </p>
{/if}
```

Is there a way to set a condition for when there aren't any entries that aren't expired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is because if ExpressionEngine does not return any results, then it doesn't even parse the tags - thus {total_entries} does not even exist in that context. Also note - it is {total_results}, not {total_entries}.

To help with this issue, EE has developed the {if no_results} conditional. Using that, your code should look as follows...

```
{if no_results}
     <p>There are no upcoming events at this time. Sign up for a our <a href="/contact/newsletter">Newsletter</a> to keep up to date.    </p>
{/if}
<h2>{title}</h2>
<p>
    {event_dates}<br />
    {event_location}
</p>
{event_summary}
```

ExpressionEngine will automatically count anything not within the 'no_results' tag as displaying if there ARE results.

Comment: Please expand on your answers (in the future) besides providing a simple code suggestion. Also, please use code blocks and other markdown in the future to make your answer's presentation more parse-able.

Comment: Hi Jason, exactly what I needed. Interesting it is not found in the Conditional documentation. Problem solved. Thank you. Also, the documentation uses total_entries: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#total-entries

Comment: total_entries, I believe, gives you a count of all the entries on the site while total_results give you a count of how many are returned in a tag pair such as channel entries.